# Best way to generate slugs (human-readable IDs) in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, slug

You know, like myblog.com/posts/donald-e-knuth.

Should I [do this with the built in `parameterize` method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252506/rails-slugs-in-url-using-record-title-instead-of-id)?

What about a plugin? I could imagine a plugin being nice for handling duplicate slugs, etc. Here are some popular Github plugins -- does anyone have any experience with them?

1. http://github.com/rsl/stringex/tree/master
2. http://github.com/norman/friendly_id/tree/master

Basically it seems like slugs are a totally solved problem, and I don't to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Stringex is the best, because it transliterates non latin urls that so much of other gems/plugins neglect.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835786/does-rails-have-an-opposite-of-humanize-for-strings might be a good reference

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I use the following, which will

- translate & --> "and" and @ --> "at"
- doesn't insert an underscore in place of an apostrophe, so "foo's" --> "foos"
- doesn't include double-underscores
- doesn't create slug that begins or ends with an underscore

```
  def to_slug
    #strip the string
    ret = self.strip

    #blow away apostrophes
    ret.gsub! /['`]/,""

    # @ --> at, and & --> and
    ret.gsub! /\s*@\s*/, " at "
    ret.gsub! /\s*&\s*/, " and "

    #replace all non alphanumeric, underscore or periods with underscore
     ret.gsub! /\s*[^A-Za-z0-9\.\-]\s*/, '_'  

     #convert double underscores to single
     ret.gsub! /_+/,"_"

     #strip off leading/trailing underscore
     ret.gsub! /\A[_\.]+|[_\.]+\z/,""

     ret
  end
```

so, for example:

```
>> s = "mom & dad @home!"
=> "mom & dad @home!"
>> s.to_slug
> "mom_and_dad_at_home"
```

Comment: but I find the result dissatisfying. For my example above, you would get mom-dad-home. I like to try preserving symbol meanings.

Comment: According to Google, dashes are better than underscores: http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=76329

`Consider using punctuation in your URLs. The URL http://www.example.com/green-dress.html is much more useful to us than http://www.example.com/greendress.html. We recommend that you use hyphens (-) instead of underscores (_) in your URLs.`

Comment: Interesting, they recommend hyphens but don't say why.

Comment: hyperlinks are very often underlined. If you use underscores, it's often difficult to differentiate between "a link" and "a_link". Hyphens don't have that issue.

Comment: +1 on the cool trick of changing @+&. You can drop the non-alpha (et al.) removal by using `.parameterize` though.

Comment: Anywhere you would use a space or hyphen in English, you should use a hyphen in a URI.

Answer (score 246):

In Rails you can use [#parameterize](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-parameterize)

For example:

```
> "Foo bar`s".parameterize 
=> "foo-bar-s"
```

Comment: Question says "in Rails" this should be elevated

Comment: Can I get a hoo rahh for build in Rails methods? Probably not because we're all developers; but, it's worth a try.

Comment: This is the best way to go about it. It's phenomenal.

Comment: There's a gotcha with parameterize. It doesn't change underscores to dashes.

Comment: `.gsub(/_/, '-').parameterize` would be the solution to addressing the gotcha @emptywalls brought up.

Comment: @YuxuanChen [dasherize](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-dasherize):
`.dasherize.parameterize`
But I'm unsure why this is a gotcha. Where is `_` not fine?

Comment: @RWDJ I was referring to what emptywalls brought up.

Answer (score 54):

The best way to generate slugs is to use the [Unidecode gem](http://rubyforge.org/projects/unidecode/). It has by far the largest transliteration database available. It has even transliterations for Chinese characters. Not to mention covering all European languages (including local dialects). It guarantees a bulletproof slug creation.

For example, consider those:

```
"Iñtërnâtiônàlizætiøn".to_slug
=> "internationalizaetion"

>> "中文測試".to_slug
=> "zhong-wen-ce-shi"
```

I use it in my version of the String.to_slug method in my [ruby_extensions plugin](http://github.com/pjg/ruby_extensions). See [ruby_extensions.rb](http://github.com/pjg/ruby_extensions/blob/master/lib/ruby_extensions.rb) for the to_slug method.

Comment: I think even better is the stringex gem http://github.com/rsl/stringex/tree/master because it uses this inside of it and also adds other usefull things.

Comment: Do you really want to convert everything to ascii?  Aren't unicode urls better for SEO?

Comment: I'm not entirely convinced about the uniode urls. I'm not sure the time has come for them. Yet. Although many disagree.

Comment: The problem is that, say if I was to write Japanese, but since Japanese borrows from Chinese all the transliterations will be based on Chinese

Comment: @Bill that's very much true. Transliteration is by no means an be-all-end-all solution. You can read about its flaws in a similar gem: https://github.com/norman/unidecoder#readme

Comment: `4 years later` @PaulMcMahon I use https://github.com/norman/babosa it doesnt convert to unicode.

Answer (score 9):

Here is what I use:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_create :make_slug
  private

  def make_slug
    self.slug = self.name.downcase.gsub(/[^a-z1-9]+/, '-').chomp('-')
  end
end
```

Pretty self explanatory, although the only problem with this is if there is already the same one, it won't be name-01 or something like that.

Example:

```
".downcase.gsub(/[^a-z1-9]+/, '-').chomp('-')".downcase.gsub(/[^a-z1-9]+/, '-').chomp('-')
```

Outputs: `-downcase-gsub-a-z1-9-chomp`

Comment: I didn't know about the parameterize inflection, I guess you could use that.

Answer (score 6):

I modified it a bit to create dashes instead of underscores, if anyone is interested:

```
def to_slug(param=self.slug)

    # strip the string
    ret = param.strip

    #blow away apostrophes
    ret.gsub! /['`]/, ""

    # @ --> at, and & --> and
    ret.gsub! /\s*@\s*/, " at "
    ret.gsub! /\s*&\s*/, " and "

    # replace all non alphanumeric, periods with dash
    ret.gsub! /\s*[^A-Za-z0-9\.]\s*/, '-'

    # replace underscore with dash
    ret.gsub! /[-_]{2,}/, '-'

    # convert double dashes to single
    ret.gsub! /-+/, "-"

    # strip off leading/trailing dash
    ret.gsub! /\A[-\.]+|[-\.]+\z/, ""

    ret
  end
```

Answer (score 6):

The Unidecoder gem hasn't been updated since 2007.

I'd recommend the stringex gem, which includes the functionality of the Unidecoder gem.

https://github.com/rsl/stringex

Looking at it's source code, it seems to repackage the Unidecoder source code and add new functionality.

Answer (score 6):

The main issue for my apps has been the apostrophes - rarely do you want the -s sitting out there on it's own.

```
class String

  def to_slug
    self.gsub(/['`]/, "").parameterize
  end

end
```

Answer (score 3):

We use [to_slug](http://github.com/ludo/to_slug/tree/master) `http://github.com/ludo/to_slug/tree/master`. Does everything we need it to do (escaping 'funky characters'). Hope this helps.

EDIT: Seems to be breaking my link, sorry about that.

Answer (score 3):

Recently I had the same dilemma.

Since, like you, I don't want to reinvent the wheel, I chose **[friendly_id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id)** following the comparison on [The Ruby Toolbox: Rails Permalinks & Slugs](http://ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_permalinks___slugs.html).

I based my decision on:

- number of github watchers
- no. of github forks
- when was the last commit made
- no. of downloads

Hope this helps in taking the decision.

Answer (score 2):

I found the Unidecode gem to be much too heavyweight, loading nearly 200 YAML files, for what I needed. I knew `iconv` had some support for the basic translations, and while it isn't perfect, it's built in and fairly lightweight. This is what I came up with:

```
require 'iconv' # unless you're in Rails or already have it loaded
def slugify(text)
  text.downcase!
  text = Iconv.conv('ASCII//TRANSLIT//IGNORE', 'UTF8', text)

  # Replace whitespace characters with hyphens, avoiding duplication
  text.gsub! /\s+/, '-'

  # Remove anything that isn't alphanumeric or a hyphen
  text.gsub! /[^a-z0-9-]+/, ''

  # Chomp trailing hyphens
  text.chomp '-'
end
```

Obviously you should probably add it as an instance method on any objects you'll be running it on, but for clarity, I didn't.

Comment: just made some improvements for your code: require 'iconv'
require 'active_support/core_ext/string'

String.class_eval do
  def slugify
    Iconv.conv('ASCII//TRANSLIT//IGNORE', 'UTF8', self.mb_chars.downcase).parameterize
  end
end

Comment: @Dmitry Yeah, “improvements”, like adding a method to every instance of String or subclass thereof. You should go ahead and include ActiveModel in there while you're at it, because non-primitives are scary!

Comment: @coreyward it is not important what class I used String class or utils, I added mb_chars call to make possible using not just english language, and replaced your regexs with parameterize, because it worked better for me.

Comment: Hmm. `mb_chars` shouldn't be necessary because Iconv is stripping anything that isn't ASCII, and ActiveSupport's `parameterize` is almost identical to what I have here. What input are you working with?

Comment: @coreyward mb_chars is necessary to make downcase work with non-english chars, iconv sucks to translit uppercase non-english chars correctly. So after some time expirementing with iconv moved to stringex gem. It makes much useful strings.

Comment: @Dmitry My use case did not entail handling more than common, non-english characters like é, thus I wanted to avoid the weight of Unidecode. If you're handling characters that are outside the capabilities of Iconv you might just want to use Unidecode instead of re-inventing the wheel, though.

Comment: @coreyward your solution is fine for many cases, Iconv works fast and almost with all languages, but I wanted more accurate results.

Answer (score 0):

With Rails 3, I've created an initializer, slug.rb, in which I've put the following code:

```
class String
  def to_slug
    ActiveSupport::Inflector.transliterate(self.downcase).gsub(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/, '-').gsub(/-{2,}/, '-').gsub(/^-|-$/, '')
  end
end
```

Then I use it anywhere I want in the code, it is defined for any string.

The transliterate transforms things like é,á,ô into e,a,o. As I am developing a site in portuguese, that matters.

Comment: FYI: There is already [String#parameterize](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-parameterize) included in ActiveSupport

Answer (score -2):

I know this question has some time now. However I see some relatively new answers.

Saving the slug on the database is problematic, and you save redundant information that is already there. If you think about it, there is no reason for saving the slug. The slug should be logic, not data.

I wrote a post following this reasoning, and hope is of some help.

http://blog.ereslibre.es/?p=343

Comment: We store the slug because it's faster to 'find_by_slug'.