# Does rails have an opposite of 'humanize' for strings?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rails adds a `humanize()` method for strings that works as follows (from the Rails RDoc):

```
"employee_salary".humanize # => "Employee salary"
"author_id".humanize       # => "Author"
```

I want to go the other way.  I have "pretty" input from a user that I want to 'de-humanize' for writing to a model's attribute:

```
"Employee salary"       # => employee_salary
"Some Title: Sub-title" # => some_title_sub_title
```

Does rails include any help for this?

### Update

In the meantime, I added the following to app/controllers/application_controller.rb:

```
class String
  def dehumanize
    self.downcase.squish.gsub( /\s/, '_' )
  end
end
```

Is there a better place to put it?

### Solution

Thanks, [fd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13956/fd), for the [link](http://rubyglasses.blogspot.com/2009/04/dehumanizing-rails.html).  I've implemented the solution recommended there.  In my config/initializers/infections.rb, I added the following at the end:

```
module ActiveSupport::Inflector
  # does the opposite of humanize ... mostly.
  # Basically does a space-substituting .underscore
  def dehumanize(the_string)
    result = the_string.to_s.dup
    result.downcase.gsub(/ +/,'_')
  end
end

class String
  def dehumanize
    ActiveSupport::Inflector.dehumanize(self)
  end
end
```

Comment: I'm oddly disturbed by the method call `dehumanize(self)`...

Comment: *grin* my attempt at humour... ;)

I also considered ".alienate(self)", but thought I'd stick with the convention.

Comment: Also config/initializers/*infections*.rb :D

Answer (score 150, accepted):

the `string.parameterize.underscore` will give you the same result

```
"Employee salary".parameterize.underscore       # => employee_salary
"Some Title: Sub-title".parameterize.underscore # => some_title_sub_title
```

or you can also use which is slightly more succinct (thanks @danielricecodes).

- Rails < 5 `Employee salary".parameterize("_") # => employee_salary`
- Rails > 5 `Employee salary".parameterize(separator: "_") # => employee_salary`

Comment: much simpler than monkey patching the String class

Comment: @giladbu but this won't work in the following case.
"author_id".humanize returns 'Author'
"Author".parameterize.underscore returns 'author'

Comment: This can be done more simply by passing the desired separation character (in this case, an underscore) as an argument to `parameterize`.  Ex: `"Employee Salary".parameterize("_")`

Comment: A minor update. This form of parameter passing will soon be deprecated. We should now use 'Employee Salary'.parameterize(separator: '_') not as short but a lot clearer.

Answer (score 3):

There doesn't appear to be any such method in the Rail API.  However, I did find this blog post that offers a (partial) solution: http://rubyglasses.blogspot.com/2009/04/dehumanizing-rails.html

Answer (score 2):

In http://as.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/String/Inflections.html you have some methods used to prettify and un-prettify strings.