# Helper for removing illegal characters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, string, url, illegal-characters

I am using a user input string to create a url and I only want the url to contain lowercase letters and hyphens

> e.g. example.com/this-is-a-url

In my model, I have added so far:

```
  def to_param
      name.downcase.gsub(" ", "-")
  end
```

This makes it lowercase and hyphenated. How can I remove all illegal characters, such as '/"$£%& and so on?  A regular expression might be the answer but is there something built in for this purpose already in Rails?

Perhaps instead of doing the above, I should create a validation that makes sure that 'name' is only spaces and letters?  Is there something built in for this purpose?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use ActiveSupport's `parameterize` method:

```
def to_param
  name.parameterize
end
```

- [`parameterize` API documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/String/Inflections.html#M001063)

Comment: I'm surprised this wasn't in the question I linked to.  +1 for the builtin approach.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider the [`to_slug`](http://github.com/ludo/to_slug/tree/) plugin for this.  See also [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1302022/best-way-to-generate-slugs-human-readable-ids-in-rails).