# Rails Cannot Parameterize Cyrillic Characters (Russian)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Our application automatically generates page URLs using a parameterized version of the page name. For example:

```
http://www.domainname.com/this-is-the-page-name
```

Simple. Works fine, except when the page name uses cyrillic characters, the parameterize method returns a blank string:

```
"Пробна галерия".parameterize
```

I've been digging online for how to deal with this, and the suggestions that I have found point towards transliteration techniques. Wondering if there is a simple straightforward way of dealing with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use gsub:

```
irb> "Пробна галерия".gsub!(/\s/,'-')
  => "Пробна-галерия"
```

Comment: We don't have a great deal of experience with cyrillic characters, but I'd rather display a romanized version of the string if is possible, UNLESS someone can confirm that displaying cyrillic chars in the address bar is standard.

Secondly, parameterize does a nice job of cleaning our output string, where gsub solution is too simple.

Comment: Then try gem [russian](https://github.com/Undev/russian) 
>Overloaded method parameterize inflector ActiveSupport (String#parameterize). Now it's a romanization of the Russian letters.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def to_slug      
  # http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1302022/best-way-to-generate-slugs-human-readable-ids-in-rails

  #strip the string
   ret = self.strip

   #replace all whitespaces and underscores to dashes
   ret.gsub!(/[\s_]+/, '-')

   #replace all non alphanumeric, non dashes with empty string
   ret.gsub! /\s*[^A-Za-z0-9А-Яа-я\-]\s*/, ''

   #convert double dashes to single
   ret.gsub! /-+/,"-"

   #strip off leading/trailing dashes
   ret.gsub! /\A[-]+|[-]+\z/,""

   ret
end
```