# Undefined method to_slug in Page controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, controller

I cant understand my this is not working. I am trying to add a method to create a slug from the title of a page when the user creates a new page (using Ruby on Rails).

This is my create method:

```
  def create
@page = Page.new(params[:page])
@page.user_id = current_user.id
@page.slug = @page.title.to_slug

respond_to do |format|
  if @page.save
    format.html { redirect_to @page, notice: 'Page was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render json: @page, status: :created, location: @page }
  else
    format.html { render action: "new" }
    format.json { render json: @page.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

end

Adn this is my method at the bottom of the same same controller. (pages_controller.rb) :

```
    def to_slug(param=self.slug)

    # strip the string
    ret = param.strip

    #blow away apostrophes
    ret.gsub! /['`]/, ""

    # @ --> at, and & --> and
    ret.gsub! /\s*@\s*/, " at "
    ret.gsub! /\s*&\s*/, " and "

    # replace all non alphanumeric, periods with dash
    ret.gsub! /\s*[^A-Za-z0-9\.]\s*/, '-'

    # replace underscore with dash
    ret.gsub! /[-_]{2,}/, '-'

    # convert double dashes to single
    ret.gsub! /-+/, "-"

    # strip off leading/trailing dash
    ret.gsub! /\A[-\.]+|[-\.]+\z/, ""

    ret
  end
```

The slug method is from this question:
[Best way to generate slugs (human-readable IDs) in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1302022/best-way-to-generate-slugs-human-readable-ids-in-rails)

I cant understand why this creates a method undefined error or how to fix it. Any help, hint or answer is appreciated. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `to_slug` method is an instance method of PagesController class. The object `@page.title` don't have this method, that's the reason why the code not working.

There are several ways to make the method `to_slug` work, such as helper, decorate. But I think the best way is to put such logic into model, because `slug` is actually part of the model. We'll make `slug` attribute available instantly before saving(create and update).

So, in `Page` model. Assume you already have `slug` attribute.

Step 1: Setup callback

```
before_saving :update_slug  # for create record, before actual saving
```

Step 2:  update_slug method

```
def update_slug  
  ret = self.title # Use title variable directly
  # .... You to_slug code. Almost same.
  self.slug = ret # return slug
end
```

The above are basic ideas to provide a thought, not verified yet. Please check and verify it by yourself. Hope that helps.