# how to make dynamic nested routes on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'll explain when open `www.domain.com/:id` should be check the `:id` is a page then use

```
get ':id' => 'pages#show'
```

else if `:id` is a Category use

```
get ':category' => 'categories#show'
```

sorry for my english

```
get ':page' => 'pages#show'
resources :categories, :path => '/' do
  resources :posts, :path => '/'
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`constraints` for `routes` is way to go, but I would suggest a bit different solution for your problem.

Consider creating custom `Constraint` objects, which will query the database in order to check if `Post` or `Category` exists:

*app/lib/post_constraint.rb*

```
class PostConstraint
  def matches?(request)
    Post.exists?(request[:id])
  end
end
```

*app/lib/category_constraint.rb*

```
class CategoryConstraint
  def matches?(request)
    Category.exists?(request[:id])
  end
end
```

In your *app/config/routes.rb*

```
get ":id" => "posts#show",      constraints: PostConstraint.new
get ":id" => "categories#show", constraints: CategoryConstraint.new
```

You have to be aware of the fact, that `id` is very poor candidate for such comparison, because the `Post` is checked in first place, and if there is record matching, the "posts#show" will be accessed, and `CategoryConstraint` wot be even bothered.

For more, check the [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#advanced-constraints).

You should consider adding a `slug` for both models to easier serve exactly what user expects to see. For this purpose, try gem [friendly_id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id).

Hope that helps! Good luck!

Comment: thank you so much, I have a problem with friendly_id doesn't support arabic characters for this I didn't used

Comment: Oh I see. I'm afraid I can't help much in that matter. You should try to generate slugs on your own (to limit possible collisions between your models of `Post` and `Category`), maybe this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1302183/4381282) will help you in your efforts of generating mentioned slugs. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

why dont you write something like this:

**routes.rb**

```
get '/:category_id/:post_id', to: 'categories#post'
```

and in your **categories_controller.rb**

```
def post
  #params[:category_id] and params[:post_id] will contain the params from the url
end
```

Comment: this is not the problem for me the problem here
get ':page' => 'pages#show'
get ':category' => 'categories#show'
when going to category route like domain.com/programming it's retrieve the page route

Comment: @Rasheed kya aap hindi me bata sakte hain apni pareshani ko

Comment: I don't understand, I don't speak this language

Comment: @Rasheed No problem.. I thought you understood hindi, coz it becomes a little difficult sometimes with non-native english speakers to communicate. btw.. I am not able to understand your problem fully .. can you please explain it a bit more

Comment: ok, I'll explain when open www.domain.com/:id
should be check the :id is page then use get ':id' => 'pages#show'  else if :id is category use get ':category' => 'categories#show'
sorry for my english

Comment: @Rasheed - please update your question with informations you've provided in the comment, so others are able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of solutions
If your post id and category id follow a pattern you can add constraints to your routes

1)

> get ':post_id' => 'posts#show', :constraints => { :id => /[A-Z]\d{5}/}
>
> get ':category_id' => 'categories#show', :constraints => { :id => /[1-9]\d{5}/ }

2) 
Add a custom method where both post_id/category_id routes point, in that check if the id is a post id or category id and based on that render the page